# NHibernate AsQueryable LINQ analogue

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I have old code to support. NHibernate is used to query DB. There are NHibernate LINQ queries like `IQueryOver.Where` and others. It works fine but I want to use these queries for local sequences. In Microsoft LINQ there is the method `Enumerable.AsQueryable`. Is there any analogue in NHibernate LINQ?

So I have this.

```
    private IQueryOver<Package> GetPackages(GetPackageMessage message)
            {
                var query = SessionFactory.Current.QueryOver<Package>();

                if (message.TzapUtc.Use)
                {
                   query = query.Where(x => x.Tzap_utc >= message.TzapUtc.ValueBegin);

                }            
                if (message.Iik.Use)
                {
                    query = use ? query.Where(x => x.Iik == message.Iik.Value);
                }
}
```

I need to apply all these Where to my local collection IEnumerable< Package>

instead of collection got from DB.

Comment: IQueryOver exposes an NHibernate-`IQueryable`-like structure if I recall.  So the two are already somewhat analogous.  That said, you are probably better off switching directly to Entity Framework over linq-to-sql for most projects.

Comment: @DavidL, [tag:queryover] has only the use of lambda in common with Linq, but nothing else. They are incompatible API. See my answer below for slightly more details.

Answer (score 1):

[queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover)* has nothing to do with Linq queries. It does not involve any queryable. Thus you cannot apply any QueryOver call on a queryable. QueryOver is a strongly typed variant of [nhibernate-criteria](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-criteria), using lambda for achieving strong typing.

If you want to use Linq with NHibernate, use [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) instead.

```
using NHibernate.Linq;

...

var query = SessionFactory.Current.Query<Package>();
```

Then you would be able of substituting your `query` with a queryable obtained from a in memory collection, using the Linq `Enumerable.AsQueryable` method.

*: or [nhibernate-queryover](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover), synonym vote pending.